# Can't boot in 12.04 after formatting the entire drive

Tags: boot, partitioning, windows

I installed ubuntu 12.04 by formatting the drive that had windows 7. The installation went fine but after I rebooted It asks me for a windows 7 disk repair disk and doesn't even look to recognize any other system. I entered the try ubuntu mode and the drive is there. The amount of space in the drive is 120GB and the drive has 119,24 in ubuntu. I can't find the drive that windows 7 use to boot anywhere. I runned boot repair but that does not seem to be the case it still does the same problem. I have a desktop.
I installed ubuntu but the boot seems messed up. I still sees windows 7 as a boot option and ubuntu doesn't boot. How can I reset the whole boot system in some way?

Comment: It's all guesswork without more information. Download the Boot Info Script (http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) and run it from a Linux emergency system. The script produces a file called `RESULTS.txt` that contains lots of information on how the disk is partitioned and what boot loaders it contains. Post a link to the script here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drive was so messed up that I needed to open a terminal and format it all the files inside even the boot history. That didn't work neither with Gparted nor boot repair.

Answer (score 2):

Is this a laptop? Make and model?

It's always handy to have a [Gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php) live on USB or CD. It is probably part of Ubuntu Live CD as well. Fire it up and check that there's no other partitions.

[image]

Note you can select disks on right hand side `/dev/sdX`:

[image]

---

Edit1:

The difference in sizes are because of GB vs GiB ([Gigabyte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte) vs [Gibibyte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte)).

```
GB  is 1,000,000,000 bytes or 10⁹
GiB is 1,073,741,824 bytes or 2³⁰
```

GB : 128 × 10<sup>9</sup> bytes = 128,000,000,000 bytes
GiB: 128,000,000,000 ÷ 2<sup>30</sup> = 119.20929 bytes (or 120 GiB)

Since GParted uses GiB the size is correct. 128 GB == 120 GiB or 119.24 GiB as shown in Ubuntu (a few bytes diff due to conversions) – and:

In some cases<sup>1</sup> a few bytes are used by HDD as further [firmware](http://www.databe.com/articles/article6.html) for the disk and S.M.A.R.T data: statistics modifications, bad sector map etc. (Meaning SMART is part of (all) HDD's but should do not affect reported size.)

```
$ sudo smartctl -i /dev/sdb
smartctl 5.43 2012-06-30 r3573 [i686-linux-3.5.0-19-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-12 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Barracuda (SATA 3Gb/s, 4K Sectors)
Device Model:     SA2000DM003-9XN234
Serial Number:    ABCDEF124
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 030303ac
Firmware Version: CC4C
User Capacity:    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   8
ATA Standard is:  ATA-8-ACS revision 4
Local Time is:    Fri Dec  7 03:19:01 2012 CET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
```

Comment: I have a desktop. I have a 128GB drive but the Gparted shows only 120.

Comment: You do not have any CD's, USB-disks etc. attached and it still asks for Windows 7 repair? And you specified to format/use entire disk on install? By "try ubuntu mode" you mean Ubuntu Live from install medium?

Comment: I installed ubuntu but the boot seems messed up. I still sees windows 7 as a boot option and ubuntu doesn't boot.

Comment: The [MBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) is messed up. It is weird and messed up that your install did not fix this. Using Boot-repair as well! One go would be to use GParted: 1. delete partition. 2. Install fresh. or try something in the lines of this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2001733

Comment: GRUB: http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/grub.html , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB